# Kotlin Map Flow of list of items

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a transaction repository from which I can get a `Flow<List<Transaction>>`.
Based on this data, I need to create a `Flow<List<Source?>>`.

The `transaction` has `sourceId` which can be passed to `sourceRepository.getSource()` which returns a source if it exists or else it returns `null`.

**ViewModel code**

```
var transactions: Flow<List<Transaction>> = transactionRepository.transactions
var sourceList: Flow<List<Source?>> = flow {
    transactions.map {
        it.map { transaction ->
            if (transaction.sourceId != null) {
                sourceRepository.getSource(transaction.sourceId)
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
    }.collect {
        emit(it)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to change the `map` of `map` and make this code less?

Comment: You can try `onEach{}` method

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can avoid `map`s here. What you can avoid is the extra `flow` builder.

```kotlin
val transactions: Flow<List<Transaction>> = transactionRepository.transactions
val sourceList: Flow<List<Source?>> =
    transactions.map { list ->
        list.map { transaction ->
            transaction.sourceId?.let { sourceRepository.getSource(it) }
        }
    }
```

Also, prefer `val`s over `var`s.